# Restful WebService in Azure: Web Role or Worker Role?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, azure

I'm trying to create a webservice and deploy it to Azure Cloud Services

The scenario is really simple: send a request via http or https to the service and receive some data.

I can't tell from documentation if this should be done in a WebRole or WorkerRole. As far as i understand a worker role can be accessed via http as well as a WebRole which runs in IIS.

can you please tell me what should i pick and why?

Thanks

Dan

Comment: what kind of services are creating? Wcf Data Services or Web Api?

Answer (score 7):

You actually have several options here, depending on what you want:

1) **An Azure Website.**

Here you can host very simply a website, nothing more. It is also cheaper than an IIS role, but you have limited access. You get a pre configured IIS where your website is published on. You can't change any setting in this IIS - you just have your Web.config.

2) **A Web Role**

You get a maintained Windows machine with a fully installed IIS on. Your application will be installed in this IIS. You can remote access this machine, you can install additionally software using start-up tasks or change the settings of the IIS itself. Microsoft takes care of system updates.

3) **A Worker Role**

A Worker Role is absolutely equally to a Web Role, except of a missing IIS. If you don't use IIS and use a custom tool to host your website, go for this.

4) **A Virtual Machine**

Well yeah, just what the name says. A virtual machine where you have to take care of the OS yourself. Install whatever you want, Windows or Linux, and set it up the way you want.

---

If you don't need any special features, go with a WebSite. If you need something that is not available on a WebSite, use a Web Role. It is also very very easy to switch from a WebSite to a WebRole later one.

Comment: hi! thanks for answer. Well, i only need a simple web-service to return some data (probably from some Azure storage in the future)  in josn format. So i guess i don t need a web role for this?

Comment: Yeah, for that I would suggest you a simple Azure Website and an ASP.NET Web API project. Currently Azure also offers a where you can host a free website with very limited resources on a shared system. For simple tests it's sufficient, and later you can upgrade to dedicated hosting with just one click.

Comment: You might also look at the Custom API feature of (the increasingly misnamed) Windows Azure Mobile Services. This allows you to create a Web API in Node.js.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn280974.aspx